# Closed form for the integral $ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 e^{\frac{-1}{\log(x)\log(y)}}dxdy ?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there a closed form for this integral?

> $$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 e^{\frac{-1}{\log(x)\log(y)}}dxdy $$

I got it from taking $f(x,y)=\frac{-1}{xy}$ and transforming $f$ via $\rho: \Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$ with $\rho(x,y,z)=(e^x,e^y,e^z)$ in order to get the integrand and secure convergence.

Comment: Can you show from which integral the desired integral is obtained, too? Because I don't see any Jacobian here... Anyway, adding some context may be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Using [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MeijerG%5B%7B%7B%7D%2C+%7B%7D%7D%2C+%7B%7B-1%2F2%2C+1%2F2%2C+1%2F2%7D%2C+%7B%7D%7D%2C+1%5D) I got that the integral could be expressed using the Meijer G-Function as $G_{0,3}^{3,0}\left(1\left|\ -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right.\right)$, but I don't know the steps you would take to get to this result. Here's also the computation of your [original integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+integral_0%5E1+integral_0%5E1+%5Be%5E%28-1%2F%28ln%28x%29ln%28y%29%29%29%5D+dy+dx) for comparison. I doubt this can be simplified any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give you an idea of the problem
$$\int_0^1 e^{\frac{-1}{\log(x)\log(y)}}dx=\frac{2 }{\sqrt{-\log (y)}} K_1\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{-\log (y)}}\right)\tag 1$$
Integrated a second time, as @Robert Lee commented the result is
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 e^{\frac{-1}{\log(x)\log(y)}}dxdy=G_{0,3}^{3,0}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 -1,0,0
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$ which is $\approx 0.223613$.

Making $y=e^{-\frac{4}{t^2}}$ make the last integral to become
$$8\int_0^\infty {t^{-2}\, e^{-\frac{4}{t^2}} \,K_1(t)}\,dt$$